# 週5日制 Can someone explain what the 制 means

Tags: meaning

週5日制

Can someone explain what the 制 means, I know it means system, but in what context in the aforementioned statement?

Comment: 制 here is short for 制度

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This indicates a "five-day-a-week system". You need to provide the context, but my guess is this is referring to the [学校週5日制](https://www.mext.go.jp/a_menu/shougai/week/index_a.htm), i.e. the idea that the school week is five days long, as opposed to (for example) six days.